# How is this "map" working?

Tags: ruby, dictionary

Could you explain what the code below is doing:

```
resp = s3.list_buckets
puts resp.buckets.map(&:name)
```

My question is specific to `map`. I am not able to understand how `map` is being used here. Also, what does `(&:name)` mean?

I referred [map documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map). However, I'm not able to correlate it with the map in the code above. Per the documentation, Map should be followed by a `{}`, but it is followed by a `()` in the code above.

In perl context, `map` will work on an array/list and will return a new array/list. So, it seems to be doing something similar here as well, but I cannot decode that.

Any pointers to documentation would be helpful.

Comment: Also: http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%26%3A

Comment: Have a look at 'with map' section of this http://www.potstuck.com/2011/08/06/ruby-symbols-instead-of-blocks/. It explain all about to_proc method of symbol that you are looking for.

Comment: @mu is too short, Thanks for referring the dups. I used `map` keyword while searching and hence did not find 'em.

Comment: @maximus, The link is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is an alias for `collect`

`map(&:name)` is shortcut for `map {|x| x.name }`

`map` expects a block. `&` calls `to_proc` on the object, and passes it as a block and Symbol has `to_proc` implemented. Refer [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) for more info

Comment: I am able to find more relevant documentation after reading "`map` is an alias for `collect`". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

& of (&:name) means what follows it should be a Proc object and will be converted to a code block.

Since & expects a Proc object, :name will be converted to a Proc object, this is done by calling :name.to_proc.

After :name is converted to a Proc object, & then converts the resulting Proc object to a code block and gives the code block to map.

In summary, there are totally two type conversions occured, one is converting a symbol to a Proc object, the other is converting a Proc object to a code block.

Comment: Thanks for +1. The explanation is a little ambiguous, so I rewrite a new one. @slayedbylucifer